# Is it possible that user can only see and access a certain file?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Hello Sharepoint experts, I'm very new to sharepoint and still doing some practice and I know some basics of it.

Is it possible that all of my users can have a different file permission to view a file? I want my users can only see/access files that are only selected for them.

I've tried creating document library view for showing the files if the user column is the same as the login user but I'm thinking its not the right way to do it because its like I'm only hiding the files.

Comment: It is possible, you can explore the options available in permissions , there are improvised much in 2013/2016 versions. Please specify the version you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

`(userA, userB, userC)` will only have ability to See/access `Document1, Document2` and `(userX, userY, userZ)` will be able to see/access `Document3, Document4` this could be done by setting up permissions

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. I did what you suggested and its working but is there a way to do it more faster like creating workflow and add a column like "user" then after adding a user, that file can only be access the user that you put to that column?

In sharepoint designer 2013, I see an instruction that you can have permission action but its not working on my end. The "app step" is enabled but no luck.

Comment: which version of sharepoint you are using?

Comment: i found this article http://spcycle.blogspot.nl/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html ... but this work only for 2010 version

Comment: I searched that staff already Sir. My sharepoint designer version is 2013 Sir.

Comment: hmm, then you'll not be able to use workflow to just achieve your goals, becaus it's work only for sharepoint 2010 and this funcunality is removed on sharepoint 2013 :/

Comment: Is it ok to use the 2010 to the sharepoint 2016?

Comment: please read this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219638(v=office.16).aspx       because if you have configured whorflow management 2010 successfully then you'll be able to use 2010 workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint 2010 workflows in 2013 and 2016 as well.

Just use impersonation step from SharePoint 2010 workflow  and it should do your job!